# IONIC Cordova build runs forever

Tags: cordova, azure-devops, ionic4, visual-studio-cordova

I'm using build pipeline to generate my app's apk, works.. but the execution never finish.

Configuration:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that the build process is successful (the final apk is built), however the script does not exit correct after? Are there any other messages after the ones shown?

Comment: Yes, are you correct. No, that's the last line of entire process.

Comment: And just to check, when you build locally does it terminate successfully? Is it just a problem with the azure build pipeline?

Comment: Yes. Apparently yes.

Comment: Try to add the --verbose flag, to show all messages on the console, maybe appear a message that said what is the problem.

Comment: Very strange indeed, my only thought would be to try with a couple of variations of the versions. Confirm the exact versions working on your local build (e.g. cordova -v and ionic info) and match in the pipeline.

Comment: Now I got this: https://i.imgur.com/7Hxkhv1.png

Answer (score 0):

Try without `--prod` argument. I had similar issue on my machine.